# Cron запуск Ruby скрипта

Tags: cron, ruby, linux

Добавляю в crontab

```
*/1 * * * * root ruby /home/www/admin/cron.rb
```

В syslog

```
Apr 30 13:01:01 cs10433 /USR/SBIN/CRON[5448]: (root) CMD (ruby /home/www/admin/cron.rb)
    Apr 30 13:01:01 cs10433 /USR/SBIN/CRON[5447]: (CRON) error (grandchild #5448 failed with exit status 127)
```

Как заставить cron выпаолнять скрипТ?

Comment: У крона своё окружение. 99% за то, что бинарника ruby просто нет в PATH. Укажите полный путь (`/usr/bin/ruby /home/www/admin/cron.rb`), ну и проверьте остальные переменные окружения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код выхода 127 - это ошибка "command not found". Либо шелл не видит ruby, либо  в скрипте вы вызываете команду, которую не видит шелл.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH ; PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH"
export rvm_env_string ; rvm_env_string='ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export rvm_path ; rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'
export rvm_ruby_string ; rvm_ruby_string='ruby-1.9.3-p392'
unset rvm_gemset_name
export RUBY_VERSION ; RUBY_VERSION='ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export GEM_HOME ; GEM_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export GEM_PATH ; GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME ; MY_RUBY_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export IRBRC ; IRBRC='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT

ruby /home/www/admin/cron.rb
```

- - - - cron.sh

Comment: System-wide инсталляция rvm - это ужасно.
   
    sudo su -
    rvm use --default 1.9.3-p392